# Styling google maps

Tags: google-maps

So, there are multiple location all over the world and we want to add a marker to each of them. But we really like the look of this map: [image]

But I can't find any information if this is even possible. Might there be other services that would allow me to show a map like that with markers?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you can not with google, you can style a map with https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ or create your own JSON https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference